# Calculated column to produce a Julian date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

In Coraswork, there is a calculation which produces a Julian date like:  19140UA.  19=year, 140 is the julian date, UA=1st calculated number of that day, if there are more than one calculated number, it will change to UB,UC, etc.   What is the formula to produce this alphanumeric?

Answer (score 0):

To convert a date to a Julian date, use the TEXT and DATEVALUE functions. For example:

```
=TEXT([Column1],"yy")&TEXT(([Column1]-DATEVALUE("1/1/"& TEXT([Column1],"yy"))+1),"000")
```

Refer to this article for more:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb862071(v%3Doffice.14)